# Matrix representation of Linear Transformation Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've been  looking for similar questions in this site but I couldn't find any, so I decided to post my question.

Let a Linear Transformation $T:\mathbb{P_2 \to \mathbb{P_2}}$ be given by the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\-2 & 1& 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$  with respect to the basis $\{ 1+x, x+x^2, 1+x^2 \}$.

Find $T(x-x^2)$. Please help me out of here, and what kind of stuff related to this topic? need reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Write down $x-x^2$ in terms of $1+x$, $x+x^2$ and $1+x^2$. The coefficients needed are the coordinates of $x-x^2$ in that basis. [Hint: one of them is $0$].
2. Multiply the given matrix by the column vector whose entries are the coordinates found. The output is the set of coordinates of $T(x-x^2)$.

Comment: i found that the coordinate of vector $x-x^2 $ respect to basis ${1+x,x+x^2,1+x^2}$ is $[1,0,-1]$ Then, multiply the given matrix by the column vector yield $[-2,-2,0]$ So, the answer is $-2-2x$, isn't it?

Comment: Almost! In the end you forgot in what base you are.

Comment: in this bases ? ${1+x,x+x^2,1+x^2}$? so what should i add then? I dont know. @Arnaud Mortier

Comment: Do what you did to get from $[−2,−2,0]$ to $−2−2x$, but with the correct basis.

Comment: what basis should i use?

Comment: @Arnauld : do you have any reference to this topic? maybe i need to learn it more.

Comment: The basis 1+x,x+x2,1+x2, the only one given in the question. The reference is any book of introduction to linear algebra, would be in the first few chapters.

Comment: Then i just need to multiply -2,-2,0 with the given basis? The final answer is in the form of set?

Comment: How did you get $-2-2x$? You did $-2$ times $1$, plus $-2$ times $x$, plus $0$ times $x^2$ right? You were using the wrong basis $(1,x,x^2)$.